# Debugging Dll's in Delphi in BPG

Tags: delphi, debugging, dll

I am debugging a bpg with multiple dll's.  Can someone tell me why my breakpoints, that DO work, eventually stop working?  The only way to get them back is to do a build all in my project group file (BPG file in Delphi 6)?

I have looked at several other posts, but have not had much luck getting an answer to this specific question.  Again, I can successfully debug, all dll's in the BPG provided I do a build all. Doing a build all every time is taking too long.

I am using Delphi6 in WinXP.

Thank you

Comment: For those that are as confused as I am: BPG is probably Borland Project Group.

Comment: this is rather non specific. Hard for us to guess what your problem is. When the breakpoints stop working how do they look in the ide? Are they the normal red colour or not? Can you see the blue dots in the gutter when the breakpoints stop working? Finally, does debugging work, or is it just the breakpoints that fail?

Comment: @David In the IDE all of the breakpoints are still there, but they are not red.  No Blue Dots either.  Debugging does still work, just some of the breakpoints fail.

Comment: @Cosmin, Yes, BPG is a Borland Project Group - a way in Delphi to collect related Delphi Projects in one place.

Comment: debugging should not work with no blue dots. This does not compute.

Comment: @David, there are blue dots for the units that still have working breakpoints.  No blue dots for the units with breakpoints that have stopped working.

Comment: do you ever build without debug, e.g. a release config?

Comment: @David, No, I don't. Why do you ask?

Comment: that would explain the disappearing dots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Delphi 6, such a failure to find debug information (all the blue lines are gone from your sources) that is solved by a complete rebuild is usually a symptom that you have to examine your project (.dpr) settings.  For each project (dll or exe) make sure a different unique compiler output folder (DCU output folder) is used.

Comment: I am wondering what your basis for this suggestion is? I should point out that not all of the blue lines are gone, just some.  Thank you.

Comment: All or some blue lines gone from your screen indicate much the same thing.  I have especially found that PAS files compiled into DCU files that are also compiled and included in a DLL target and that are included also in an EXE target, seem to trigger either compiler or linker glitches, that lead to this situation.  Not sharing DCU output artifacts seems to reduce or eliminate the incidence of this problem.